# Using Request to post from NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am running into an issue with posting a json doc via request from my nodeJs app.
The problem is for me how to pass the json doc to post. Here is what works for me

```
const options = {  
url: 'http://localhost/message/send/981f1507-2df2-4011-8f55-5460897fcde6',
method: 'POST',
json: true,

body: { "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "html",
      "content": "</p>\r\n\r\n<ul type=\"disc\">\r\n\t<li><strong>Ready to Use Experiences</strong> &ndash; Get instant access to our fully configured and integrated environments allowing you to use and experience the products as a customer would in their own deployment. We&rsquo;ve set up the products alongside partner solutions so you can experience the entire ecosystem including Office 365, Salesforce, and more.&nbsp;</li>\r\n</ul>"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "test@ueser.com"
        }} ]}}}




request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

the problem i have is if i want to pass the body from a string like this

```
var mybody = `{ "message": {
"subject": "Meet for lunch?",
"body": {
  "contentType": "html",
  "content": "This is a test"
},
"toRecipients": [
  {
    "emailAddress": {
      "address": "test@user.com"
    }
}]}}`
```

and then call it like this

```
const options = {  
url: 'http://localhost/message/send/981f1507-2df2-4011-8f55-5460897fcde6',
method: 'POST',
json: true,

body: mybody
}

request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

which throws errors like

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `stringify`? Node.js has a a built in module called `querystring`.

```
const querystring = require("querystring");
const myStringBody = querystring.stringify(myBody);
```

Then write it to your request.

```
req.write(myStringBody);
```

Comment: I got a bit further and it seems that if you pass an object to the body it as to be a actual object and not a valid json string. When i converted my json to object it worked.

Comment: So it seems if i have a Json Doc i want to pass i have to use JSON.parse to convert it back to java object in which case it works fine. Strange that you can not pass a valid json doc in body directly